# How to create different translation version for 1 word document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, language, microsoft-office-2013, translation

I have an usage manual and I have translated I have to translate them into different languages.

At first, Normally this is what I supposed to do; I should create a new page or new file for each language and tanslate each paragraph sentence.

This sound okay. However, since I will be updating my usage manual frequently, sometimes I will lose the control of translation of different languages.

This is how it was supposed to work; for instance, there will be one and only word document. When I select a sentece I will choose transate - language. I will translate and write there.

When I do it for all sentences for different languages, 1 work document will have different version for each language but they will be under 1 document.

I will be able to switch between them easly, By this way, everything will be easy to control. When I update I will have more control.

Do you have any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

We Have ourselves a large volume of product manuals that are written primarily in Dutch and then translated for our international customers. Most documentation is written in Help&Manual, but also in Word, PowerPoint, Illustrator and HTML.

To ease translation into many languages we use a piece of software called OmegaT. It is a free and powerful translation program. Initial translation is as difficult as before, but when only part of the manual is changed it automatically detects what has changed using the translation memory saved as XML. You just need to maintain the changed text translations.

We have been working like this for five years now with now 11 languages and approximately 8 products. It works great and efficient. Especially since OmegaT integrates well with svn. Find more info at OmegaT.org or google "omegat dotnetnuke video" for a sample. Good luck!